# Is it bad practice having only two methods but using Route:: apiResource?

Tags: laravel

I'm curious about your thoughts.

Let us say I have these two methods:

```
Route::get('/shoppingcart', 'CartController@index')
     ->name('cart');
Route::post('/shoppingcart', 'CartController@store')
     ->name('cart.store');
```

I just wanted to write:

```
Route::apiResource('shoppingcart', 'CartController');
```

Would you say it is bad because other routes are registered as well? (Show, Destroy, Update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Partial Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) to only include certain crud operations.

```
Route::resource('shoppingcart', 'CartController')->only([
    'index', 'store'
]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not been clear enough, I just want to know if it is bad practice if I leave the "only" part out? Is it bad if I have these routes registered or not?

Comment: What would be the reason to keep the routes registered? These might generate errors if the controller functions do not exist.